# How to compare two time columns in mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I want to check time availability from mysql using php and here is my table

```
id      employeeid          booking_starttime           bookingclosetime
1       4                   1565347980                  1565349300
1       4                   1565360100                  1565364900
```

Now i have dynamic `booking_start_time(1565346900)` and `booking_end_time(1565350500)` and i want to check whether `booking_starttime(varchar)` and `booking_endtime(varchar)` exist in
database between this time then how can i do this ?

Comment: pass your require time in timestamp formate between start and close time.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra: can your write query please so i can check

Answer (score 1):

See if you have any two timestamps you can just simply compare them like this as they are number only.

```
Select * from table where booking_starttime < bookingclosetime
```

Now your answer to your question:

> Now i have dynamic booking_start_time(1565346900) and
>   booking_end_time(1565350500) and i want to check whether
>   booking_starttime(varchar) and booking_endtime(varchar) exist in
>   database between this time then how can i do this ?

```
SELECT * FROM table where booking_start_time = '1565346900' AND booking_end_time = '1565350500'
```

Comment: actually i have two dynamic parameters(start_time and end_time) which i want to compare with database saved "booking_starttime" and "booking_endtime" but your query will not work for this

Comment: Okk so pass that timestamp to start time and end time respectively, I suppose you are already saving timestamp in db

Comment: you are right , please listen carefully my requirment

I WANT TO COMPARE database time with my parameters whether my parameters time exist( whether they come between paramers ) or not

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provide the between keyword that will perform this kind of operation for you

```
Select * from table where :date between start_date and end_date
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Comment: your query maybe wrong because i dont want to match just date i am trying to match datetime

Comment: Between check if a value is contained in a range  (inclusive limits). Type, here, won't matter.

Comment: whats wrong with following code , its not working

if(($req_stime>=$bookedstime || $req_stime<=$bookedetime) || ($req_etime>=$bookedstime && $req_etime<=$bookedetime))
      {
       echo "exist";
      }
      else
      {
       echo "not exist";
      }